# Convert flat table to XMLA c#

Tags: c#, json, olap

Is it possible to create a XMLA result from a JSON or ADO connection.

I need to create a simple service that return a XMLA result but I don't have MS SQL OLAP in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using the example from MS [Generating Dynamic Methods with Expression Trees](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2009/09/14/generating-dynamic-methods-with-expression-trees-in-visual-studio-2010/)